# What casting problem on my query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Work on C# vs2008.my bellow query show me error.Can any body tell me what's the problem and how to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

```
 NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
 List<Order> r = (from p in db.Orders
                  select new { p.OrderID, p.OrderDate });
```

Error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to assign a query expression to a `List<>` object. That's wrong.

You need to call `ToList()` to convert the results of the query to a list of orders found, and use an anonymous type since you're selecting only partial data and creating new anonymous objects:

```
var r = (from p in db.Orders
         select new { p.OrderID, p.OrderDate }).ToList();
```

Note that the anonymous type will still be enumerable as it's still a generic `List<>`, and as such it still implements the generic `IEnumerable<>` interface.

To form a `List<Order>`, you need to either retrieve complete objects, so `select p` instead as John Rasch says:

```
List<Order> r = (from p in db.Orders
                 select p).ToList();
```

Or `select new Order`s and build them out of the fields that you're selecting.

Comment: above syntax show this error message Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<NewTypeWork.Order>'

Comment: @shamim - if you want a list of `Order`s, replace `select new { p.OrderID, p.OrderDate }` with just `select p`, then use the `ToList()` as BlockClock suggests.

Comment: @shamim: Yeah I missed that. You're selecting a subset of data, so you won't be getting a list of complete `Order` objects.

Comment: plz see the question ,than reply why i use var instead of list,i want to avoid anonymity.i know if i use p instead of new keyword it's work fine.Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

```
 NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
        List<Order> r = (from p in db.Orders
                 select p).ToList();
```

Selecting `new {...}` creates a new instance of an anonymous type. If you want to select an `Order` you will have to return Orders from your query. Finally you have to call ToList() because Linq queries return `IEnumberable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Or depending what you will do with that query later, keep it as a IQueryable (which will allow you further filtering and querying on the server without pulling all orders), by doing:

```
using (var context = new NorthwindDataContext())
{
  var allOrders = from p in db.Orders
               select new { p.OrderID, p.OrderDate };

  // Here you can do further processing (to be executed in DB)
  var someOrders = allOrders.Where(ao => ao.OrderDate < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1));
  Console.WriteLine(someOrders.Count()); // <-- Query will execute here
}
```